# Control of whitespace when using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, formatting, white-space

Probable duplicate. When using `\includegraphics` to insert PDF figures in text  (double-column format), I find I need to make use of `\hspace` and `\vspace` in order to get the figure and the follow-on text appear in the right place. But this requires me to adjust the value of the length parameter for every new picture to make it appear in the right place. Is there a way to avoid need for `\hspace` and `\vspace`, or have their values adjusted automatically? Here is a sample:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{c}
\vspace{-4cm}\\
\hspace{-1.2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{foo} \\
\vspace{-7.5cm}\\
\hspace{-1.2cm}
\end{tabular} \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\vspace` in a tabular `c` column do nothing useful, normally you just want`\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{foo}\caption{zzz}\end{figure}`

Comment: The best solution is to remove the white space in the image itself.  Next best is to use [clip, viewport= or trim=] (see graphicx manual).

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
```

if you use the optional argument it is almost always best to include `p` as not doing so greatly increases the chances of the figure going to the end of the document. Also `!` should only be used for "difficult cases" never as a default usage.

```
\begin{center}
```

The environment form adds vertical space which you do not want here as `figure` already adds vertical space. Use `\centering`.

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
```

The `tabular` is doing nothing here: it can be deleted.

```
\vspace{-4cm}\\
```

This negative space is partly compensating for the vertical space added by `center` but -4cm will mean that if the `h` option is used it will over-print text above the figure, and even `t` option positioning will make it overprint the page head. if the problem is white space in the image this shoudl be fixed by trimming using the options to `\includegraphics` or (better) fixing the image using an external editor before inclusion.

```
\hspace{-1.2cm}
```

This forces the image to over-print the left margin. Again would be better addresses by trimming the image.

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{foo} \\
```

OK but the `\\` should be removed once the surrounding `tabular` is removed.

```
\vspace{-7.5cm}\\
\hspace{-1.2cm}
```

These spaces match the ones before the image so can be removed for the same reasons.

```
\end{tabular} \end{center}
```

As noted above both the `tabular` and `center` can be removed.

```
\end{figure}
```